Android App: Is it possible to get camera access through the android head unit of a car?
I would like to know if it's possible to get camera access from an Android head car unit. I've been working on this project for a while but I'm not sure if I'm missing a step. But, I'm out of wits on what to do here.
The Android head unit's OS is Android 13.
Here is the flow:

App -> opens -> request for camera permission -> opens single camera prompt -> camera in front of car opens. -> It is now receiving footage from the front car and displaying it in the Android head unit.

Note: This is a 360-degree camera car system. Specifically this brand, QCY A8334 [4+64G] 9 inches 360 View Camera 9 inch Android 13 Touch Screen Bluetooth Double Din Car Stereo Support Voice Command, Carplay/Android Auto, Steering wheel control, WiFi, FM.
I tried to work on it by changing the code and using different camera libraries apart from CameraX
But, the only thing I saw was that Camera Failed, or when trying to use the request permission it just shows black when trying out the singleCameraActivity.java

"It is now receiving footage from front car and displaying it in android head unit" -- this sounds like it is working.

@CommonsWare Oh I'm sorry I didn't make that clear. I meant like the flow I wanted the app to do. That's the thing I'm trying to figure out. The reason why I can't access the cameras from the 360 system.
